# 'serve the best interest of' or 'serve the best interests of'?

Tags: grammatical-number

The sentence is

> Our vision is to become an employer of choice where our employees
>   serve the best **interests** of the residents of our County.

(Should it be *interests* or *interest*?)

Comment: *Best interests* is idiomatic.

Comment: @Lawrence So are 'in/serve the best interest of'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For what it's worth, Ngram link: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=best+interest+of%2C+best+interests+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbest%20interest%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20interests%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You are free to use either; the plural form shows that you may well be considering the problem to be complex.

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth about problem complexity. Put another way, do you consider the residents to have a (single) unified "best interest" or multiple metrics of success / fulfilment?

Comment: @Lawrence AFWIW, Google hits for "serve the best interest of" :  "serve the best interests of" are apparently 4.3m : 1m.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It depends on what is being 'served'. Example of the singular: "It is in your best interest to ... ." In the OP's *specific* example, I think the plural is more natural (and dare I say, idiomatic) due to the implicit complexity of issues concerning the residents. I don't think this is an instance in which singular version works - "... serve the best interest of the residents ..." suggests an over-simplification of the residents' aggregated perspectives.

Comment: You're overlooking the fact that the mass-noun usage is equally available here. It's more common (according to Google results) to say, for instance, "It's in your interest to ...".

Comment: The presumption is that there's more than one interest.

Answer (score 1):

"Interests" is correct, just as you have written it. The residents of your County have more than one "best interest." Don't overthink it.

Comment: By this reasoning, "in our remits to" might be expected to have more then a single Google hit (Collins Reverso Dictionary allows the plural). And certainly 'in our own image'seems far more common than 'in our own images' in a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

The wording "best interests" (plural) has a well-established idiomatic sense in U.S. law. *Black's Law Dictionary*, fourth edition (1968) has this in its entry for *best*:

> **BEST.** Of the highest quality; of the greatest usefulness for the purpose intended. For example:
>
> ...
>
> The "best interests" of a child whose custody is in question has reference more particularly to the moral welfare than to mere comforts, benefits, or advantages that wealth can give [Citation omitted.] The "best interests" of an estate mean the greatest or most advantage or usefulness to such estate. [Example omitted.]

So while the "best interests" of someone or something in a legal setting may involve applying a single criterion (such as "best result for the moral welfare of the child" or "most advantageous outcome for the estate") and may point to a particular decision or policy or judgment, the notion that multiple considerations or interests are in play is implicit in the use of the plural *interests*.

In the OP's example, the wording seems to be invoking the legal idiom of "best interests" in a nonlegal setting.

A Google Books search for "the best interest of" (blue line) vs. "the best interests of" (red line) for the period 1700–2005 yields the following Ngram chart:

[image]

For much of the past 200 years, as the chart shows, "the bests interests of" has been far more common than "the best interest of"; and even in 2005 the former is about twice as popular as the latter. In the pat 50 years or so (through 2005), however, the gap between the two has become much smaller. I suspect that this reflects the use of "the best interests of X" by people who aren't fully aware of the usual legal form. Numerous matches from 1998–2005, for example, refer to "the best interest of the child" rather than the more traditional "the best interests of the child."

Examples of "the best interest of" do go back a long way (to [1717](https://books.google.com/books?id=EDEJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA153&dq=%22the+best+interest+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBqKGwnbrJAhVE2GMKHepNC1E4bhDoAQhLMAY#v=onepage&q=%22the%20best%20interest%20of%22&f=false), [1754](https://books.google.com/books?id=3Xs-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22the+best+interest+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ3JWwnLrJAhUFpIgKHZWQDFw4ChDoAQhWMAk#v=onepage&q=%22the%20best%20interest%20of%22&f=false), and [1779](https://books.google.com/books?id=fKtgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA111&dq=%22the+best+interest+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuz4Lum7rJAhUPlIgKHXESB1sQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20best%20interest%20of%22&f=false), in Google Books search results), but the plural variant was well on its way to dominance by 1800.

Conclusion: Both the singular form and the plural form are in current use. but it appears that "the best interests of" remains the more frequent form (though by a diminishing margin). Especially in a legal or quasi-legal context, it may be the better bet.